# Dumping unique information from a for loop into a class item

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, variables

*Bear with me as I'm a new, self-taught python developer and I'm sure I'm using some pretty abysmal conventions/practices. Also, my first post on stackoverflow.*

I'm writing a live timing program that pulls information from an SDK for drivers within a practice/qualifying/race session. This is updated every second.

Ultimately all of this information is printed back out within the terminal in a particular format.
(There will be a UI once the initial information is correct.)

Within the SDK there are two different sections where I need to pull information.
SessionInfo is sorted by car position.
DriverInfo is sorted by carID.

SessionInfo has CarID information that can be tied to the same number CarID in DriverInfo.

I figured that the easiest way to perform this, along with updating all of the data acquired, would be to create this class so that the information is global:

```
class Driver:
def __init__(self, DICarID, SICarID, DICarNum, DIIrating, DILicString, Position, ClassPosition, DIUserName, CurrentTime, FastestLap, FastestTime, LastTime, LapsComplete, Incidents, ReasonOutStr):
    self.DICarID = DICarID
    self.SICarID = SICarID
    self.DICarNum = DICarNum
    self.DIIrating = DIIrating
    self.DILicString = DILicString
    self.Position = Position
    self.ClassPosition = ClassPosition
    self.DIUserName = DIUserName
    self.CurrentTime = CurrentTime
    self.FastestLap = FastestLap
    self.FastestTime = FastestTime
    self.LastTime = LastTime
    self.LapsComplete = LapsComplete
    self.Incidents = Incidents
    self.ReasonOutStr = ReasonOutStr
```

Then ultimately using a for loop, gather the information for each CarID and write it to Driver().

The only way I can think to do this would be to create unique variables. I'm told this is a bad idea unless there's a good reason to dynamically generate variables within a loop.

ie:

```
driver(x) = Driver(driverInfo['CarIDx'], sessionInfo['CarIDx']...)
```

I'm not certain of the proper way to perform that.
Maybe it's easiest to go with the recommended method of creating a list.

Any help would be appreciated. I'll edit this with more info if it's needed.

EDIT: I was asked why I was storing SICarID and DICarID if they were identical. In retrospect, maybe dividing SI data and DI data into their own seperate classes would be the way to go. However, the initial idea is to pair those two numbers just to debug and verify that the associated data is correct.

```
print(driver.DICarID, driver.SICarID)
```

Currently would display:

```
0 10 
1 2
2 14
3 12
4 6
5 16
6 1   
7 4 
8 0
9 7       
10 8
11 11
12 19
13 5  
14 13
```

There are other drivers in this particular session not being displayed since they have not posted a time.

Here is how the information is formatted currently within the string (heavily redacted):

```
SessionInfo:
 Sessions:
 {
  ResultsPositions: #In positional order
  {
  Position: %d
  ClassPosition: %d
  CarIdx: %d
  Lap: %d
  Time: %.3f
  FastestLap: %d
  FastestTime: %.3f
  LastTime: %.3f
  LapsLed: %d
  LapsComplete: %d
  LapsDriven: %.3f
  Incidents: %d
  ReasonOutId: %d
  ReasonOutStr: %s
  }
 }
DriverInfo: #In order of carID
 Drivers:
 {
 CarIdx: %d
 UserName: %s
 UserID: %d
 TeamID: %d
 TeamName: %s
 CarNumber: "%s"
 IRating: %d
 LicString: %s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

Yes, you want to put your `Driver` instances in some sort of container so you can easily retrieve and handle them.

**Comments**

The "container" may be a `list` as you suggested, or perhaps a `dict` having the `DICarId`s as keys and the corresponding instances as values - this has the advantage that you can directly access the `Driver` you need.

But if you're going OOP, go OOP: define another `class` (will it be `Race`?) and keep your drivers in a member of that `class`. The functions you will create which deal with a single driver will be `Driver`'s methods; those which deal with more than one driver will be `Race`'s methods.

Even more OOP: you have practice/qualifying/race sessions. So some of the members of your `Driver` are really session data. Once again, define a `Session class`, and store the `Session` instances for a driver in that driver's `Driver` instance. In other words you will have one `Race` instance which contains a few `Driver` instance references, and each `Driver` instance in turn contains a few `Session` instance references. Assuming you created a my_race variable of `Race` type, you will have something similar to:

```
my_race #the whole race
my_race.drivers #the dict containing the drivers for that race
my_race.drivers[DICarId] #a driver in the dict
my_race.drivers[DICarId].sessions #the sessions for that driver
my_race.drivers[DICarId].sessions['qualifying'] #the qualifying session for that driver
```

(One last question: why are you defining two members, `DICarId` and `SICarId`? Aren't they supposed to be exactly the same value? Why storing it twice?)

Comment: I've gone ahead and made an edit above to reflect your final question.

The rest of this I will comprehend when I have a little more time tonight!